# Creating CSS circles in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm having some trouble creating CSS circles in react-native.  The following works in iPhone 6 Plus but in all the other iPhones, they become diamonds.

```
circle: {
  height: 30,
  width: 30,
  borderRadius: 30,
}
```

Now if I use PixelRatio on `borderRadius` it works in everything but iPhone 6 plus.  iPhone 6 plus renders it as boxes with rounded corners.

```
circle: {
  height: 30,
  width: 30,
  borderRadius: 30 / PixelRatio.get(),
}
```

Comment: I don't know Why but In my case, border radius twice the size of width and height made a perfect circle. https://snack.expo.io/@waleedbutt98/border-radius

Answer (score 118):

Your border radius should be a half of width and your height. like below:

```
circle: {
   width: 44,
   height: 44,
   borderRadius: 44/2
}
```

Comment: `borderRadius: '50%'` throws an error in React16 and RN 0.49. I just tried it before Googling and finding this page.

Comment: in android it's not looking like circle , it's like round rect

Comment: On Android pixel ratio 3: (width=64, border-radius=32) => rounded rect; (width=64, border-radius=64) => circle. On iOS pixel ratio 2: (width=64, border-radius=32) => circle; (width=64,border-radius=32) => diamond shape. Difficult to adjust for both

Answer (score 64):

None of these fit my needs, if you need a **responsive** circle you can try using my solution:

**Step 1**: Import **Dimensions** *(and other used elements)* from react native (or add to existing imports list)

```
import { Dimensions, TouchableHighlight, Text } from 'react-native';
```

**Step 2**: Add your touchable element *(you can calculate width or height of a device)*

```
    <TouchableHighlight
      style = {{
        borderRadius: Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width + Dimensions.get('window').height) / 2,
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5,
        backgroundColor:'#f00',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}
      underlayColor = '#ccc'
      onPress = { () => alert('Yaay!') }
    >
      <Text> Mom, look, I am a circle! </Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

**Step 3:** Enjoy your responsive circled element

[image: React-native circle button]

Comment: Still fully not circular on S10 phone

Answer (score 38):

borderRadius should be half the side of the square. So 15 in your case - no matter what pixel ratio the device has.

It works with `30 / PixelRatio.get()` only for 2x retina devices, cause the result is 15.
Then for iPhone 6 Plus, you indeed get a rounded box because the result is 10 (pixel ratio is 3).

I'm surprised your saying it worked on iPhone 6 Plus with 30 for a 30x30 square.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why `PixelRatio.get` doesn't work and reinforcing that we should just use 50% of the square side.

Answer (score 24):

If you want to make a circle that will work on any device the only thing that you should do is to give the same `height` and `width` the same value and then give the `borderRadius` a really high value I personally give it 1000 so it will big enough for most of the cases

```
circle :{
 height : 30 ,
 width :30,
 borderRadius: 1000,
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Good answer, you added example. Added explanation. Keep up the good work.

Comment: I think a more stable way to build circles on react native is making sure that the borderRadius value is exactly half of the width and height. On some devices this circle might look strange or cropped.

Comment: This results in a rounded rectangle on Android.

Answer (score 14):

Since borderRadius style expects number as a value you can't use borderRadius: 50%. To make circle all you have to do is use your image width/height and devide it with 2.  Read more here:
https://github.com/refinery29/react-native-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 8):

Basically just need to apply same `height, width` and in `borderRadius` have to divided by 2

E.g. `height : 50, width :50 borderRadius : 50/2`

**Just Circle**

```
var circle = {
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    borderRadius: 15
}
```

**Responsive Circle with Device Height**

```
var circle = {
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.1,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.1,
    borderRadius: Math.round((Dimensions.get('window').height + Dimensions.get('window').width) / 2)
}
```

**Responsive Circle with Device Width**

```
var circle = {
    height: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.1,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.1,
    borderRadius: Math.round((Dimensions.get('window').height + Dimensions.get('window').width) / 2)
}
```

**Example Code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { Dimensions, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')

function roundOff(v) {
    return Math.round(v)
}

function dimensions() {

    var _borderRadius = roundOff((height + width) / 2),
        _height = roundOff(height),
        _width = roundOff(width)

    return { _borderRadius, _height, _width }
}

export default function ResponsiveCircle() {

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.circleView}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Responsive{'\n'}Circle
                </Text>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )

}

const commonStyles = { alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: { flex: 1, ...commonStyles },
    circleView: { height: dimensions()._height * 0.2, width: dimensions()._height * 0.2, borderRadius: dimensions()._borderRadius, backgroundColor: 'tan', ...commonStyles },
    text: { textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: 25, color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold' }
})
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Can we add text in exact position in this circle? I want to create a fragrance wheel, can this approach work?

Comment: @HardikShah one suggation => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc3G-bO1p8Q&ab_channel=CatalinMiron

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the `styled-components` package to style my React Native components and the easiest solution I've found is to set the `border radius` to a size in px larger than half of the width that the circle will ever have. It'll then default to the equivalent of a 50% border-radius for any size smaller than that.

Answer (score 2):

`onLayout` worked for me.

Calculate width and height to maintain 1:1 aspect ratio, then set borderRadius to width/2

```js
const [circleSytle, setCircleStytle] = useState();
...
function calCircleStyle(layoutEvent) {
  let {width, height} = layoutEvent.nativeEvent.layout;
  let dim = width > height ? width : height;

  setCircleStyle({width:dim, height:dim, borderRadius:dim/2});
}
```

Then apply it to your view like this:

```js
<View onLayout={calCircleStyle} style={circleStyle}>
...
</View>
```

Btw, can anyone explain why `borderRadius:1000` is bad?

Comment: It's possible a circle will one day grow beyond that size, even if we can't foresee how right now. Also, anyone looking at the code in the future might wonder if 1000 is significant or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know its an old question but i wanted to reply with the easiest way.
Just set borderRadius property with a high value, it will automatically do a circle. With this solution you **dont** need to specify **width** or **height**. (I will because i only have a View with no content)

```js
/* Component */
<View style={styles.button}></View>

/* StyleSheet */
button: {
   width: 80,
   height: 80,
   backgroundColor: "#000000",
   borderRadius: 1000 // High value
}
```

[image: Photo of the above code]